# camunda 7: multi tenancy architecture choice to scale a spring boot application on cloud

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant, camunda

I have following scenario

- BPMN workflows managed by a workflow service with embedded camunda 7
- hundreds of tenants but i want schema separation so that tenants can be region migrated
- in every request to service tenantId is present

I am considering below options (instead of discriminator column) ::

- so, if i use option 1 - one process engine per tenant and a dynamic datasource for that engine,
  will this scale?
- Is there a way to cleanup not so frequently used engines based on a LRU/LFU cache?
  I want to manage a cache of 50 engines and delete engine and datasource using a cache.. on every pod ..
- option2 - It is unclear from the docs how the table prefix option works ?  Any help here?

thanks
rajans

my implementation has only 1 tenant.  so now moving to multi tenant - in design phase.